# Plotting boolean matrix using nested while loop

Tags: python

I am currently working on software to control the navigation of a robot within a field. I have create a 96x96 matrix of 0's and 1's to signify where my robot is within the field at the moment. To help with trouble shooting/modeling I have created a function that, using nested while loops, plots all the 1's on the graph. The robot is 8x8 so it should appear as 8x8 in the bottom right hand corner of my plot. Instead, it appears as a vertical line 0-7 on the y-axis.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#Desc: shows 96x96 matrix
def plotMatrix(matrix):
    i = 0 # row count
    j = 0 # column count   
    # cycle through rows->columns to plot values
    while i < 96: # 96 is array size
        while j <96:
            if matrix[i][j] == 1:
                plt.plot(i,j,'ro')
            j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
    plt.axis([0,95,0,95])
    plt.grid([0,95,9,95])
    plt.show()
#-------------------------------------------------
```

A 96x96 graph is shown with 0-7 filled in on the y-axis. It should produce this, but mirrored 0-7 for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 on the x axis.

Comment: using `plt.scatter` is likely what you're after here I suspect - `plt.plot` is the default for line plots. Also consider looking at `plt.matshow` as well as representing your matrices as `numpy` arrays (i.e. you could have an array for the grid and one for the robot)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise a `numpy` array for the empty grid as follows:

```
import numpy as np

grid = np.zeros((96, 96))
```

Then you can create a robot:

```
robot = np.ones((8, 8))
```

Then you can determine where you robot starts by broadcasting it into the grid

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grid = np.zeros((96, 96))
robot = np.ones((8, 8))

def place_robot(matrix, robot, x=0, y=0):

    robot_size_x, robot_size_y = robot.shape
    robot_end_x = x + robot_size_x
    robot_end_y = y + robot_size_y
    if robot_end_x > matrix.shape[0] or robot_end_y > matrix.shape[1]:
        print("You cannot place the robot here")
    else:
        matrix[x:robot_end_x, y:robot_end_y] = robot
    return matrix, robot

grid, robot = place_robot(grid, robot, 1, 1)
plt.matshow(grid)
```

Hopefully you can see how this builds and use it as a jumping off point to allow you to move the robot, etc. This is placing the robot using the upper left corner as a reference for the robot and the grid, but you can play around with this easily enough.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: This is very helpful - thank you! We will need be using this to track and edit navigation controls. Is this code still two different arrays where I am not able to use the matrix in order to process navigation logic?

Comment: Well, once you've placed the robot, you can treat it as a single array and use a get_location function integrated with a move_robot function to move it around. I would suggest moving the robot using vectors, and a similar logic as here to determine whether the move is legal. Of course, this is just one approach, you could use a square object on a `matplotlib` canvas and get more granular control of location, rotation and position.

Comment: for tracking, look at `np.where` which can identify the current location